# How to define by user which field name to get from JSON in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am able to read JSON in Unity when I specify field name by variables names in my class with JsonUtility. I want to make my script more generic so user can define which field name to use from multiple JSONs, which don't necessary use same field names.

```
// call this function to get array of JsonEntry objects
public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
{
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<JsonEntries<T>>(json).Entries;
}
```

I am using this classes

```
[Serializable]
public class JsonEntries<T>
{
    public T[] Entries;
}

[Serializable]
public class JsonEntry 
{
    // field names from one JSON example
    public string USULAN_ID; 
    public string USULAN_LAT;
    public string USULAN_LONG;
    public string USULAN_URGENSI;

    //TODO user defined filed names
}
```

Is it possible to let user define which field name to use, if I don't know the field names in advance with using JsonUtility in Unity?

Comment: You could use an UI Input field

Comment: Not using the JsonUtility, no! With the JsonUtility you have to know the fieldnames beforehand and have classes implemented representing the structure of the json including the exact matching field names.

Comment: Ok derHugo, got it, JsonUtility is a deadend. I will try SimpleJSON. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not using the [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html), no!**

With Unity's `JsonUtility` you have to know the field names beforehand and have classes implemented representing the structure of the JSON including the exact matching field names. And it is also limitted to certain types:

> The API supports any `MonoBehaviour`-subclass, `ScriptableObject`-subclass, or plain class/struct with the `[Serializable]` attribute. The object you pass in is fed to the standard Unity serializer for processing, so the same rules and limitations apply as they do in the Inspector; only fields are serialized, and types like `Dictionary<>`; are **not supported**.
>
> Passing other types directly to the API, for example primitive types or arrays, is **not currently supported**. For now you will need to wrap such types in a class or struct of some sort.

---

Assuming you need this only in one single level and a JSON looking like e.g.

```
{
    "USULAN_ID":"some id", 
    "USULAN_LAT":"some lat",
    "USULAN_LONG":"some long",
    "USULAN_URGENSI":"some urgensi"
}
```

where the field names and count may change dynamically you could use [`SimpleJSON`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON). In order to do so simply copy the content of `SimpleJSON.cs` into an accordingly named new file in your project and add `using SimpleJSON;` to a script where you want to use it.

And in the scene I would simply use a [`Dropdown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Dropdown.html) to let the user decide which field to use

```
using SimpleJSON;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DropDownController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Components References")]
    public Dropdown dropdown;

    [Header("Input")]
    // Where ever you get the json data from
    public string JsonString = "{\"USULAN_ID\":\"some id\", \"USULAN_LAT\":\"some lat\", \"USULAN_LONG\":\"some long\", \"USULAN_URGENSI\":\"some urgensi\"}";

    [Header("Output")]
    public string currentlySelectedKey;
    public string currentlySelectedValue;
    public Text selectedValueText;

    private Dictionary<string, string> entries = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        // get the component
        if (!dropdown) dropdown = GetComponent<Dropdown>();

        // register a callback 
        dropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(HandleValueChanged);

        // where ever you need to call this method
        UpdateOptions(JsonString);
    }

    public void UpdateOptions(string jsonString)
    {
        // parse the string to a JSONNode
        var json = JSON.Parse(jsonString);

        // unfortunately SimpleJson simply returns null
        // and doesn't throw any exceptions so you have to do it on your own
        if(json == null)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat(this, "Oh no! Something went wrong! Can't parse json: {0}", jsonString);
            return;
        }

        // for the case this is called multiple times
        // reset the lists and dictionaries
        dropdown.options.Clear();
        entries.Clear();

        //optional add a default field
        entries.Add("Please select a field", "no field selected!");
        dropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData("Please select a field"));

        // JSONNode implements an Enumerator letting
        // us simply iterate through all first level entries
        foreach (var field in json)
        {
            // simply assume string keys and string values
            // might brake if the provided json has another structure
            // I'll skip the null checks here
            var key = field.key;
            var value = field.value;

            entries.Add(key, value);
            dropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData(key));
        }

        // set default
        dropdown.value = 0;
        HandleValueChanged(0);
    }

    private void HandleValueChanged(int newValue)
    {
        currentlySelectedKey = dropdown.options[newValue].text;
        currentlySelectedValue = entries[currentlySelectedKey];

        // optional visual feedback for the user
        selectedValueText.text = currentlySelectedValue;
        // optional color feedback for not yet selected
        selectedValueText.color = newValue == 0 ? Color.red : Color.black;
    }
}
```

[image]

---

*Note: Tested with `Unity 2019.1`; `Dropdown` might work different in `2019.2` since the UI was changed.*

Comment: Thank you derHugo. SimpleJSON served my needs perfectly. Your solution with dropdown many makes also perfectly sense...